# How to find speed with friction?

Tags: physics

You testify as an expert witness in a case involving an accident in which car A slid into the rear of car B, which was stopped at a red light along a road headed down a hill. You find that the slope of the hill is θ = 14.5°, that the cars were separated by distance d = 22.0 m when the driver of car A put the car into a slide (it lacked any automatic anti-brake-lock system), and that the speed of car A at the onset of braking was v0 = 18.5 m/s.

(a) With what speed did car A hit car B if the coefficient of kinetic friction was 0.60 (dry road surface)?
m/s

(b) What was the speed if the coefficient of kinetic friction was 0.10 (road surface covered with wet leaves)?
m/s

How can this be solved? The book says , a = g sin angle - coefficient cos angle = a negative numver. But when I try it, the number is positive...

Comment: As an expert witness you're probably supposed to base this on actual **physics** as opposed to naive mathematical models. This therefore becomes more of a physics question. Note for example that the friction for a car is **not** modelled using coefficient of friction.

Comment: @skyking This is obviously an artificial word problem that involves a fictional and irrelevant expert witness for the story.

Answer (score 1):

Let the $x$ axis be along the road, downwards and let the $y$ axis be perpendicular to the road upwards. Projection of gravitational acceleration on the x-axis is $g\sin{\theta}$ and $-g\cos{\theta}$ on the y-axis. Friction is along the negative $x$ axis and is $F_{xf}=-\gamma{v_{x}}$.
Newton along $x$ is
$$\dot{v}_{x}=g\sin{\theta}-\frac{\gamma}{m}{v_{x}}$$
the solution is
$${v_{x}}(t)=\frac{mg}{\gamma}\sin{\theta}-\frac{mc}{\gamma}e^{-\frac{\gamma}{m}t}$$
At $t=0$ the speed was $v_{0x}$, so
$$c=g\sin{\theta}-\frac{\gamma}{m}v_{0x}$$
And the solution with initial conditions is
$${v_{x}}(t)=(1-e^{-\frac{\gamma}{m}t})\frac{mg}{\gamma}\sin{\theta}+v_{0x}e^{-\frac{\gamma}{m}t}$$
Use your numbers and calculate